# Undeclared scope error while accessing private variable defined in header file

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am getting the following error by executing a cpp program :

```
Board.cpp: In function ‘Queen Board::* getQueen(int)’:
Board.cpp:5:5: error: ‘queens’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘Queen’?
    5 |     queens.size();
      |     ^~~~~~
      |     Queen
Board.cpp:6:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
    6 | }
      | ^
```

Here is the minimal reproducible code for it

**Board.cpp**

```
#include "Board.h"

Queen Board::*getQueen(int index)
{
    queens.size();
}
```

**Queen.h**

```
class Board;
class Queen
{
public:
    Queen();

private:
};
```

**Board.h**

```
/** @file Board.h */
#ifndef _BOARD
#define _BOARD
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "Queen.h"

using namespace std;
class Board
{
private:
    vector<Queen *> queens;

public:
    Queen *getQueen(int index);
}; // end Board
#endif
```

I am not sure what's the reason for the error as I am simply accessing a private variable
of the class

Comment: `Queen Board::*getQueen(int index)` -> `Queen* Board::getQueen(int index)`, voting to close as typo.

Comment: Or maybe it needs a word of explanation: `*` is a part of the return type, not of the function. Therefore, it must not be placed in the middle of (qualified) function name, but rather near the return type. Most C++ conventions tell to glue `*` to the name of the type rather than the other token, which makes it easier to understand IMO.

Comment: You already asked this in [Variable not declared in this scope Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67444792/variable-not-declared-in-this-scope-error). The convention on SO is to edit your question to improve it, not spam multiple copies of the same question.

Comment: More explanation: `Queen Board::*getQueen(int index)` declares a function named `getQueen` taking an `int` parameter and returning a [pointer-to-member](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_members), specifically a pointer to a `Queen` member of the `Board` class (`Queen Board::*`).

Comment: @JaMiT ok Will follow that. I thought that one is over.. Will edit next time

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thanks that was helpful. It was probably due to following bad convention that this simple error got unnoticed. Is there a good guideline or page for C++ convention, coding style etc ?